# Captions on an image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make "meme"-looking captioned images with CSS using an `<img>` object and two `<p>` objects styled with CSS. Right now I have a `<div>` which contains the `<img>` and then the two `<p>`'s. What I want to do is have the picture positioned in the top-left corner of the div and then I set the `z-index` to -1 and THEN somehow position the two p objects over the image but positioned relative to the top-left corner of the div.

This is so I can set the `top: y` and `left: x` values of the p objects such that they will be positioned accordingly relative to the top-left of the div and in turn the image.

But when I try to set `position: relative` for the p objects there's a problem where the first p is correctly placed but the 2nd p is positioned relative to the first one so even though it's at `top: 0, left: 0` it's still lower than it should be.

How can I fix this?

Comment: ...and what's a *meme-looking caption*? Is there an example anywhere?

Comment: http://Quickmeme.com. It's essentially a photo that's captioned with something that has very little to do with the actual photo itself.  Variations are created, making a meme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/56J8y/1/

relevant CSS

```
.meme_container {
 position: relative;   
}
.meme_container .top_meme {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.meme_container .bottom_meme {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

​

and the html

```
<div class="meme_container">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"/>
<p class="top_meme">This is a caption 1</p>
<p class="bottom_meme">This is a caption 2</p>
</div>​
```

Comment: No; put your answer *here*, in the *answers*.

Comment: This almost works but what's happening is the text is appearing not in the corner like it should but slightly lower and WAY lower when the `left:` and `top:` values are anything other than 0.

Comment: @StickFigs, Im not sure what you're after.  Changing the left and top values will definitely move the text from the corner, as those are the positions from the left and top of the image, respectively.  As seen in the JSFiddle above, the text is right in the corner.

Comment: @Kirean Right, but when I try to do it on my website the (0,0) position isn't in the top left corner it's all the way to the left but slightly down. I don't know why it's happening.

Comment: Nevermind, I had to set the <p> padding and margin to 0, now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Pseudo element like `:after` and `:before`

Example:

```
img:after {
   content: "Hello, I am the caption";
}
```

Comment: while this is a good illustration of actual photo-captioning, not what the OP is asking for with a "meme-caption"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about this situation:

```
<div>
  <img />
  <p class="first">caption1</p>
  <p class="second">caption2</p>
</div>
```

Then to do what you want you need to set the positioning of the div to something (relative will generaly not affect your behaviour so its a good choise). Once that is done postioning absolute can be used inside. Absolute refers to the next higher positioned element!!

```
div{position:relative};
p{position:absolute};
p.first{top:10px};
p.second{top:20px};
```

Comment: absolute does not refer to the next higher positioned element, but allows you to position an element relative to the first parent with a position other than static.   http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning   Relative positioning allows you to maintain normal document flow, but position the element relative to where it would normally occur (by offsets), which is why it "will generally not affect your behaviour".  Incidentally, relative is not just a good choice, but the right choice in this situation.